# Action text content displays incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, trix, actiontext

ActionText content in my Rails project appears like this

[image: Action Text Content]

This is how I am trying to render it on the erb file

`<%= item.content %>`

Item is a model, which looks like

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

I am following the example on the documentation but not sure why it is not rendering without the key

Comment: What's the HTML look like? Are you seeing the `<div class="trix-content">`?

Comment: Was this an existing field in the dB or is this a new attribute?